# Viewsonic 4k monitor has no video after fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, 4k-monitor

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 using a 1080p monitor because my motherboard doesn't output BIOS information to HDMI. After the install completed, I disconnected the 1080p monitor and plugged the HDMI 4k monitor back in and powered on the computer. On first boot there was no display. So I connected the 1080p monitor back and completed the initial configuration. Then I went into display settings and switched the 4k monitor's resolution to 1080p and then back to 4k and it started working. Then after the system went to sleep it wouldn't wake up again and I had to do the same resolution change again to get it to work. Is there any way to fix this so it always figures itself out after waking up or booting up?

xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5760 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 connected 1920x1080+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1440x900      74.98    59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
HDMI-0 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 700mm x 400mm
   3840x2160     60.00 +  60.00    59.94*   50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98    23.98  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.93    59.94  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Information about the monitors by running the following command: `grep "NVIDIA(GPU-0)" /var/log/Xorg.0.log |head -17| cut -d\: -f2`

```
 ViewSonic VA2431 Series (DFP-0)
 ViewSonic VA2431 Series (DFP-0)
 ViewSonic VA2431 Series (DFP-0)
 
 ViewSonic VX3211-4K (DFP-1)
 ViewSonic VX3211-4K (DFP-1)
 ViewSonic VX3211-4K (DFP-1)
 
 DFP-2
 DFP-2
 DFP-2
 
 DFP-3
 DFP-3
 DFP-3
 
 DFP-4
```

Here is information on the video card from `lspci`

```
0d:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 162
    Memory at f5000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```